# How do I ask about two different possible options?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is this the correct way to ask which of two options is true?

> あの CD は　トルコご　の　ですか　えいご　の　ですか？

("Is that CD in Turkish or English?")

Comment: Should questions ask why they suspect what they have said is incorrect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically,

> あのCDはトルコ語のですか、英語のですか？

in fact means

あのCDはトルコ語の(CD)ですか、英語の(CD)ですか？

that is, "This CD, is it a CD of/about Turkish, or a CD of/about English?"

If you say

> あのCDはトルコ語ですか、英語ですか？

then you mean "This CD, is it in Turkish, or is it in English?"

Answer (score 4):

> あのCDはトルコ語のですか、英語のですか？

Is correct, although

> あのCDはトルコ語ですか、英語ですか？

is more common for asking what language the CD is in. If the content is about Turkish/English themselves, then the former is more common.

Comment: The former one reads 

    あのCDはトルコ語の(CD)ですか、英語の(CD)ですか？